# Flex 3: ConcurrencyError using HTTPService

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, httpservice

I'm getting occasional ConcurrencyError faults when using HTTPService in Flex 3. I have four HTTPService objects, all configured with concurrency=single. I'm not sure though how to continue to diagnose, as I don't see in the FaultEvent what service object caused the issue, and I can't easily reproduce it on-demand.

One feature of my app is that I am also using a URLRequest to load a sound shortly after receiving a result from one of the HTTPService calls. Could this be related to the concurrency error?

The fault looks like this:

```
[FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="Attempt to invoke while another call is pending.  Either change concurrency options or avoid multiple calls." faultCode="ConcurrencyError" faultDetail="null"] messageId=null type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh. I'm going to call it a bug in Flex 3.2 because upgrading to 3.4 got rid of it.